# TRIGGER THAT UPDATES A COLUMN FROM INSERTED ROW (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, trigger

Basically I need a trigger that updates a column of the inserted row, where it takes a value from another table by comparing the foreign key.

Something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post what you have written so far

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: TRIGGER UPDATE_PRECO_VENDA_CAMPO 
AFTER INSERT ON MARCACOES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MARCACOES(preco_venda_campo)
    SELECT  preco_atual
    FROM    PRECO_ALUGUER_CAMPOS
    WHERE cod_preco_campo = :new.cod_preco_campo;
END;

Comment: this trigger compiles, however when i try to add a new row it gives this error: table MARCACOES is mutating, trigger cannot read or modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger you posted as a comment raises the error because you're trying to literally **insert** value into a table which is just being affected by the trigger; as the table is being modified, trigger can't see it (and that's a well-known *mutating table* error).

Though, it is not `insert` you need but `update` - again, not literally, just select desired value into appropriate column, referenced via the `:new` pseudorecord.

Tables you posted as a screenshot differ from code you posted so I'm just trying to show *how* to do it; can't tell whether it'll actually compile or not (depends on real table and column names).

```
create or replace trigger update_preco_venda_campo
  before insert on marcacoes
  for each row
begin
  select preco_atual
    into :new.preco_venda_campo
    from preco_aluguer_campos
    where cod_preco_campo = :new.cod_preco_campo;
end;    
/
```